# Is it possible to open another form with specific panel view in winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, desktop-application

i want to move from one form to another form contain multiple panels. and i need to view that one specific panel from it. I wanted to move back to previous page and that previous page is another form, it has three panels and i need to view the second panel from it..

```
    private void linkLabel2_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Mainp mainf = new Mainp();
        mainf.Show();

    }
```

Above code just switch the form but with default panel, I have set...but along with this, I need to view panel 2..
please help...thanks in advance

These are the screenshots for the forms..
[image: This is my home image and my first form]
[image: This is the same form but this is the result of panel switch and this is the panel I need to view when I press the previous button]
[image: This is the second form]

Comment: See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: I read your description. But I didn't understand the relationship between forms. And what is the panel you said? Can you elaborate them?

Comment: Mine is a steganography project...the first form consist of three panel. the first panel shows options to choose between image or audio steganography. and second and third panel shows options to embed or extract for image and audio respectively. and the second form views the form for extract or embed accordingly. i need to go back to first form and it should view my second panel. hope you understood.

Answer (score 0):

i have found my answer... i just to make the panel access from private to public to access it...i have to make the panel access of my main form from private to public and now i can access the panel from other form.